# What are these circles that keep appearing in online inspector?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Every time I inspect my code, there is a circle that appears. Does anyone know what this is?

[image: Snippet of HTML code in inspector]

Edit 1:
Thank you to Sam I now know that they are text nodes. I am having a little trouble identifying where they are in my code. If anyone can spot them and point them out to me it would be much appreciated.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'parts/shared/header' ); ?>
    <?php 
        if(have_posts()) : ?>

        <div id="main-content">

            <div id="inside">

                <div class="content">

                    <div class="container">

                            <div class="padding_30">

                                <h1 class="page_header_blog">Blog</h1><br>

                                    <div class="blog_wrapper">

                                        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                        <div class='post'>
                                            <div class='thumbnail'>
                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 32 ); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <h2 class='each_blog_info' id='post-<?php the_ID(); ?>'></h2>
                                            <div class='blog_info'>
                                                <small><i class='fa fa-calendar-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                                                <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>&nbsp;&#10072;&nbsp;
                                                <i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                                                <?php the_author() ?>&nbsp;&#10072;&nbsp;                                       
                                                <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?>
                                                </small>
                                            </div>
                                            <h2 class='blog_title_link'><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' rel='bookmark' title='Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>'>
                                            <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                            <div class='excerpt'>
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                                                  
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>                                      



        <?php endif;?>
                                    <div class="text-center"><?php

                                    the_posts_pagination( array(
                                    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'spafix' ),
                                    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'spafix' ),
                                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'spafix' ) . ' </span>',
                                    ) );


                                    ?></div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

<?php get_template_part( 'parts/shared/footer' ); ?>
```

This is the code from my index.php page where the text nodes are apprearing in inspector. They appear after the loop with the div class of 'post'.

Answer (score 0):

This is "text nodes", they are generated by not accurate PHP and contain " ".

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These are due to white spaces... Generally when two or more nodes which inline-block property comes together